# How can i multiply specific number in vector using R

Tags: r

I have task to multiply numbers in vector, but only those that can be divided by 3 modulo 0. I figured out how to replace certain elements in vector by different numbers, but it works only if i replace with certain number. I wasn't able to find any answer here http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector or even on this site. Everyone only extracting values to another vector.

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
x[x%%2==0] = 5
# [1] 1 1 5 5 5 3 3
```

why this doesn't work ?

```
x[x%%3==0] = x*3
```

I expect to get this:

```
c(1,1,5,5,5,9,9)
```

Comment: Your rhs is not the same length as lhs i.e. `x[x%%3==0] <- x[x%%3==0]*3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment vectors are not the same on the `lhs` and `rhs` of the assignment operator.

```
length(x*3)
#[1] 7

length(x[x%%3 ==0])
#[1] 2
```

We need to do

```
x[x%%3==0] <- x[x%%3==0]*3
x
#[1] 1 1 5 5 5 9 9
```

Instead of repeating the logical vector, an object can be created and then do the substitution

```
i1 <- x%%3 == 0
x[i1] <- x[i1]*3
```

---

In the first assignment, there was only a single element and it was assigned to replace the values returned by the logical condition is met

---

Another option is

```
pmax(x, x*(!x%%3)*3)
#[1] 1 1 5 5 5 9 9
```